# NRPT via GPO while using Always On VPN NRPT

Tags: windows, vpn, group-policy, nrpt, alwaysonvpn

I have a working Always On VPN Profile deployed using the ProfileXML implementation of automatic NRPT to the local device configuration:

```
<DomainNameInformation>
<DomainName>.example.internal</DomainName>
<DnsServers>10.0.0.1,10.0.0.2</DnsServers>
</DomainNameInformation>
```

Which also is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/operating-system-security/network-security/vpn/vpn-name-resolution#name-resolution-policy-table-nrpt)

> NRPT is set using the VPNv2/<ProfileName>/DomainNameInformationList node of the VPNv2 CSP.

Now I want to add a second domain to the clients resolving to an internal DNS server without rolling out a new configuration to every client. So I wanted to add a NRPT via GPO to either selected or all clients using the VPN profile I already deployed.
The moment the GPO is applied, the NRPT rule automatically created by the connected VPN is removed/delete from the system.
This can be validated using PowerShell cmdlets `Get-DnsClientNrptRule` and `Get-DnsClientNrptPolicy`.
Even if I reconnect the VPN to trigger recreation of the rules, they don't appear anymore.
The only NRPT left on the system is the one from the GPO.

This prevents internal name resolution and makes name based resources unavailable.

In the official [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn593632(v=ws.11))

> If NRPT rules are present in multiple GPOs that apply to the same user or computer, the rules are merged, with more discrete rules taking precedence over more general rules.

There is also no indication in the [DomainNameInformationList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/vpnv2-csp#deviceprofilenamedomainnameinformationlist) that there is any option helping me solving the problem.

Partial solutions:

- Adding a second section to the ProfileXML - both domains are added to the local NRPT. [This would require a new rollout to all clients - not desired]
- Adding the first/original domain to the GPO of the second domain. [This prevents dynamic NRPT depending on the VPN state.]

How can I mix GPO NRPT with Always On VPN ProfileXML-NRPT?

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't have much knowledge about NRPT. Now If NRPT is anything like other settings that can be enforced by GPO, GPO almost always take priority and override settings from other places. This is the purpose of GPO after all, to enforce. It merges settings from its own hierarcy (OU, domain. site, local), so maybe it's by design that it does not necessary pick up and keep settings from VPN.